# Both variables are the same, however calculating a=b disagrees?

Tags: vba, excel

On my Workbook, I have a sheet called "check"

Where the CELLS have the values:

```
F8 = 176129.20
H8 = 176129.20
```

My VBA code is a basic validation script which checks boths cells and displays messages based on the outcome.

```
Function plchk()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("check")

    qb = sheet.Range("F8").Value
    xl = sheet.Range("H8").Value

    If qb = xl Then
        plchk = "They're the same"
    Else
        plchk = qb & "  " & xl
    End If

End Function
```

Should be pretty straight forward when I compare qb = xl the THEN should be executed, however instead VBA doesn't recognise them as the same and goes down the ELSE route and outputs both numbers with a space, and they're exactly the same number. I'm lost! Variable types?

Whomever helps me i send out good karma to you inadvance!!

Comment: I assume the cells have different types: eg. text and number

Comment: Can't I reparse them in VBA?

Comment: I initially thought that but on the worksheet they're both formatted as numbers.

Comment: You could cast them to integer using 'CINT(sheet.Range("F8").Value)' or if you want to use stings use' CSRT(sheet.Range("F8").Value)'

Comment: if you use `cint` you'll lose the decimal values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Function plchk()

Dim sheet As Worksheet, qb as double, xl as double
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("check")

qb = cdbl(trim(sheet.Range("F8").Value))
xl = cdbl(trim(sheet.Range("H8").Value))

    If qb = xl Then    
        plchk = "They're the same"    
    Else    
         plchk = qb & "  " & xl
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks fella, worked fine. So what's going on here with cdbl and the trim?

Comment: `trim` in order to delete spaces in case one or both fields were text values and `cdbl` to cast the values to decimal numbers

Comment: if your question is answered please use the tick next to my answer in order to mark the question.

Comment: As soon as I tried your suggestion, I went for the tick, it didn't let me apparently I have to wait for 5 minutes. I'll wait. Thanks again man!